# Restrict access to property from outside the class

Tags: c#

Let's have this class:

```
ExampleClass
{
    public List<string> MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

The question is how to restrict outside classes to modify of that property, means add object to collection, make new().

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> MyValue {get; private set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could expose it as `IEnumerable<string>` instead of as a list. This interface will not allow adds. You can still store it as a list internally, as a private field, so that the class itself can add or remove if needed.

For example:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    private List<string> _myValue = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var s in _myValue) yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

If the caller would like to work with its own list, it can of course do this:

```
var list = exampleClass.MyValue.ToList();
```

At which point the caller owns it and it is clear that anything it chooses to add has nothing to do with the original list.